# dynamically create element with onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm obviously missing something, but I haven't been able to find what I am doing wrong and I have been staring at this for entirely too long

```
function message(options) {
  ...
  options.onclose = options.onclose || null;
  ...
  this.gui = document.createElement('div');
  this.msg = document.createElement('div');
  ...
  if (options.onclose != null) {
    var close = document.createElement('i');
    close.innerHTML = 'close';
    close.className = 'material-icons close';
    close.onclick = options.onclose;
    console.log(close.onclick);
    this.msg.append(close);
  }

  this.msg.innerHTML += options.msg;
  this.gui.append(this.msg);
  ...
  return this.gui;
}

msgContainer.append(new message({
    class: 'update',
    sticky: true,
    icon: 'mic',
    msg: 'You are in a call',
    onclose: () => { console.log('click'); }
  }));
```

from the developer console `document.querySelector('.close').onclick is null`, but if I add an on click `document.querySelector('.close').onclick = () => { console.log('click'); };` it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!  setting innerHTML makes chrome rebuild the dom and in the process it loses the onclick event, onclick works fine if I use textContent instead of innerHTML.  In the below example if you comment out the last line of JS the onclick works, here's the same thing in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/706gwu9t/)

```
var blah = document.getElementById('blah');
var div = document.createElement('button');
div.style['background-color'] = 'black';
div.style.padding = '20px;';
div.style.innerHTML = 'a';
div.onclick = () => { alert('wtf');};

blah.appendChild(div);

// Uncomment this to make onclick stop working
blah.innerHTML += ' this is the culprit';

<div id="blah">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it wont work is because on click is a function:

```
document.querySelector('.close').onclick
```

doesn't do anything so why call it.

```
document.querySelector('.close').onclick = () {
     alert("did something");
}
```

so the real question is what do you want to do when clicked? create a new link or div.. look below. I would start using jQuery.

jQuery answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".myclass").click(function(){
          $(".container_div").append("<a href='test.php'>test link</a>");
          // also .prepend, .html are good too
     });

});
```

Comment: I just missed the => in the post above, I'll update it.. trying to avoid jQuery where possible.  after doing `document.querySelector('.close').onclick = () => { console.log('click');`  onclick returns `() => { console.log('click'); }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example. I changed your code a little bit. You can add more events by passing it to an array. I used addEventListener.

```js
var msgContainer = document.getElementById('msgContainer');

function message(options) {

  options.onclose = options.onclose || null;

  this.gui = document.createElement('div');
  this.msg = document.createElement('div');

  if (options.onclose != null) {
    var close = document.createElement('i');
    close.innerHTML = 'closepp';
    close.className = 'material-icons close';
    close.dataset.action = 'close';
    this.msg.append(close);
  }

  this.msg.innerHTML += options.msg;
  this.gui.append(this.msg);

  // Create listeners dynamically later on
  events = [ 
   { selector: close.dataset.action, eventType: 'click', event: options.onclose }
  ];

  renderElement(this.gui, events);
}

function renderElement(element, events) {
 msgContainer.append(element);
  
  for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
   var currentEvent = events[i];
        var selector = element.querySelector('[data-action="' + currentEvent['selector'] + '"]');

   selector.addEventListener(currentEvent['eventType'], currentEvent['event'].bind(this), false);
  }
}



new message({
    class: 'update',
    sticky: true,
    icon: 'mic',
    msg: 'You are in a call',
    onclose: () => { console.log('click'); }
  });
```

```html
<div id="msgContainer">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you not add the onclick to the element before it is added to the dom?

Comment: I ended up using `this.msg.innerHTML += '<i class="material-icons close" onclick="('+options.onclose+')()"'+'>close</i>';`  I was under the assumption that innerHTML = and creating an element in js would work more closely than they do.  Thanks